# How to use ServiceStack Templates to support dynamic results based on request type?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

With [ServiceStack's Razor Story](https://docs.servicestack.net/view-and-template-selection) we have a variety of ways of selecting which Razor View we want to use to render a page.  Even better, and critical in my case, is we can pass in a Content-Type header (or query string parameter, or even page "suffix") as well to return the raw model in a [variety of formats](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types).

Is there any way to use [ServiceStack Templates](http://templates.servicestack.net/) (now known as [SharpScript](https://sharpscript.net/)) to do the same thing?  I follow the example [here](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/api-pages#dynamic-api-pages) but I just get back the standard HTML format response.  It doesn't use my template, no matter how named.

Following the example in the [v5.5 Release Notes](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#sharp-apis):

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request) => new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" };
}
```

Going to `/hello/World?format=html` provides me the standard HTML report, not my template.  I followed another example to force it to use the template ....

```
public object Any(Hello request) =>
        new PageResult(Request.GetPage("examples/hello")) {
            Model = request.Name
        };
```

... and it ALWAYS returns my template, even if I specify `/hello/World?format=json`.

Is there any way to have Razor-like view selection for ServiceStack + ScriptSharp pages, but also support different response formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer a vague question like this without details of a specific scenario you want to achieve that's not working.

You can return [Sharp Pages](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-pages) in a number of ways:

- When it's requested directly as a content page, e.g `/dir/page` -> `/dir/page.html`
- Using [Page Based Routing](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-pages#page-based-routing), e.g `/dir/1` -> `/dir/_id.html`
- As a [View Page](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-pages#view-pages) in response to a Service when it's named after the **Request DTO** or **Response DTO**, e.g `/contacts/1` -> `/Views/GetContact.html` or `/Views/GetContactResponse.html`

Select which view to render inside your Service by returning your Response DTO inside a custom `HttpResult`:

```
public object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    ...
    return new HttpResult(response)
    {
        View = "CustomPage",  // -> /Views/CustomPage.html
        //Template = "_custom-layout",
    };
}
```

Add the `[ClientCanSwapTemplates]` Request Filter attribute to let the View and Template by modified on the QueryString, e.g: `?View=CustomPage&Template=_custom-layout`

```
[ClientCanSwapTemplates]
public object Any(MyRequest request) => ...
```

Choosing which page you want to render inside your [Model View Controller Service](https://sharpscript.net/docs/model-view-controller) by returning a custom `PageResult`:

```
public class CustomerServices : Service
{
    public object Any(ViewCustomer request) =>
        new PageResult(Request.GetPage("examples/customer")) {
            Model = TemplateQueryData.GetCustomer(request.Id)
        };
}
```

> Note: That the `SharpPagesFeature` resolves pages using your cascading `AppHost.VirtualFileSources`. In .NET Core it's configured to use its **WebRoot**, e.g `/wwwroot`.

For Sharp Pages to return its Response in Multiple Content Types:

> as well to return the raw model in a variety of formats.

You need to use a [Sharp APIs](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apis) which `return` a value, e.g. [/hello/_name/index.html](https://github.com/NetCoreWebApps/Blog/blob/master/hello/_name/index.html):

```
{{ { result: `Hello, ${name}!` } | return }}
```

Comment: I think there was a gap in the docs, or at minimum my understanding.  I dug into the code and realized it was implemented almost exactly like Razor ViewPage selection.  I just returned an `HttpResult` with a `View` property set to my template page name ("account" in this case) and voila!  I think another case of analysis paralysis & not seeing this spelled out in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

To succinctly answer my own question, the first option from @mythz is what I needed.  After calling `Plugins.Add(new SharpPagesFeature())` in my `AppHost`, I needed to return `HttpResult` from my service method:

```
public object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    ...
    return new HttpResult(response)
    {
        View = "CustomPage",  // -> /Views/CustomPage.html
        //Template = "_custom-layout",
    };
}
```